# How do I have achieve a combined line limit for two Text views in a VStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, vstack

I have a design that I want to achieve in SwiftUI, and there are three examples shown below.

[image]

It's a `VStack` that contains an `Image`, and two `Text` views.

1. It should show no more than three lines of text, ie the container view should not grow in height if both Text views would have enough text for two rows
2. It should not shrink in height when there is only one line of text for each text view.
3. It should support dynamic font sizes

Comment: When both are two lines, should the title take priority?

Comment: Nice request...

Comment: If the font size is the same for both, and if bold can be applied by using embedded formatting, and if the title will never exceed 2 lines, then you could concatenate the two texts into one and insert a newline in the middle. Then you could use `.lineLimit(3)`. But that's a lot of *ifs*.

Comment: I have no idea why this question gets 1 downvote...

Comment: @son Someone went through my posts and downvoted many of them.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know either. However, if one of these answers is helpful, could you take a look and give feedback?

Answer (score 3):

regarding the idea with the placeholder, you can use native solutions such as `.lineLimit(3, reservesSpace: true)`

Comment: Good suggestion, didn't know about this possibility! (+1)

Comment: Wow, nice catch! I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the implementation should go like this which will guarantee your conditions I think.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var title = "Title text"
    @State var subTitle = "Subtitle text"
    
    var isSubtitleLarger: Bool {
        subTitle.count > title.count
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .lineLimit(isSubtitleLarger ? 1 : 2)
            
            Text(subTitle)
                .lineLimit(isSubtitleLarger ? 2 : 1)
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 150) // Add minimum height to meet minimum size, so that the view doesn't shrink when texts are small 
    }
}
```

This is important to guarantee there is always **3 lines at max**.

Comment: This doesn't take the font size into consideration. So you might end up truncating the title to 1 line if the subtitle is longer, even though the subtitle fits on one line but the title actually needs two.

Comment: Font size is same for title and subtitle too. If in a larger font size a longer subtitle fits on 1 line then in the same given environment the title (which is shorter) will also fit in 1 line. If subtitle is longer it will always need more space than the title as the font size is same for both.

Comment: Agree, it works if the font size is the same for both. But might not work if this is not the case.

Comment: Yes, there could be some marginal error when different font style applied on title and subtitle. But with some simple analysis the relational size difference can be figured out and applied on this solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to accomplish this. I'm assuming the title and subTitle will have a maximum of three lines. The idea is to create a Text with a placeholder that has up to three lines. Then add the overlay of your two title and subTitle `View`s to this placeholder.

```swift
struct TextWrapper: View {
    private let maxLines = 3

    let title: String
    let titleFont: Font
    let subTitle: String
    let subTitleFont: Font

    var body: some View {
        Text(" ")
            .font(titleFont)
            .lineLimit(3, reservesSpace: true) //Autofill the height with x lines
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .hidden()
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                VStack {
                    if title != "" {
                        Text(title)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .lineLimit(maxLines)
                            .layoutPriority(2) //Title has higher priority
                    }
                    
                    if subTitle != "" {
                        Text(subTitle)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .lineLimit(maxLines)
                            .layoutPriority(1)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This is the output when `titleFont = .title3` and `subTitleFont = .subheadline`:

[image]

**Updated**: As @Benzy pointed out in his comment, the placeHolder string could be sufficient with title, subTitle, and extra new line (\n). However, I decided to keep it as a dummy text cause there are cases when either `title` or `subTitle` are empty, even both of them.

**Updated 2**: Removed placeholder stuff since @miltenkot gave idea on `reservesSpace`.

Comment: I think it is always difficult to estimate the placeholder size to fit and meet 3 lines considering different widths of devices available.

Comment: I would suggest a simpler placeholder. Assuming the width is fixed (which is why the wrapping is seen), then the placeholder is only needed for determining the height. So "X\nX" for the title and "X" for the subtitle should be sufficient. Then add `maxWidth: .infinity` to the placeholder, to use the full width too.

Comment: If for the both Text() we keep lineLimit 3 it should end up in showing 6 lines in worst case. Isn't it?

Comment: @BenzyNeez Thanks for pointed this out, I didn't notice that, will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`.layoutPriority()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/layoutpriority(_:)) !

This view modifier basically shrinks the least prioritized views before the more prioritized views when resizing is necessary.

This is how you could use it:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Title")
        .lineLimit(2)
        .layoutPriority(1)
    
    Text("Subtitle")
        .lineLimit(2)
        // The default layout priority is 0 so you don't need to set it explicitly
}
```

Comment: In worst case you will end up showing 4 lines. To test the scenario check with big lines for title and subtitle too.

Comment: This doesn't restrict the combined text to 3 lines. So in the first example, the second text will still wrap to two lines, making it 4 lines in total.

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is all about restricting the height of the combined text so that there is only space for three lines. Actually, if you don't want the height to shrink when there are less than 3 lines (ref. your second requirement) then there must *always* be space for exactly three lines.

One way to do this is to use a hidden placeholder, as *son* has tried to show with his answer.

Another way would be to calculate the height for the text block, based on the font size. Unfortunately, `Font` does not let us read the font properties, but a `UIFont` does. And a `Font` can be created from a `UIFont`.

Regarding the third requirement:

> 3. It should support dynamic font sizes

When a `Font` is created from a `UIFont`, it does not adapt automatically to changes to the text size in the settings. As a workaround, a `ScaledMetric` can be used to adjust the chosen font sizes.

So here is how it can be solved using a computed height for the text block:

```swift
struct ThreeLineText: View {
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let textBlockSpacing: CGFloat = 4
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) private var fontRefSize: CGFloat = 100

    private var titleFont: UIFont {
        .systemFont(ofSize: 20 * fontRefSize / 100, weight: .bold)
    }

    private var subtitleFont: UIFont {
        .systemFont(ofSize: 15 * fontRefSize / 100)
    }

    private var maxTextBlockHeight: CGFloat {
        (titleFont.lineHeight * 2) + textBlockSpacing + subtitleFont.lineHeight
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: textBlockSpacing) {
            Text(title)
                .font(Font(titleFont))
                .lineLimit(2)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

            Text(subtitle)
                .font(Font(subtitleFont))
        }
        .frame(height: maxTextBlockHeight, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

Trying it with your example cases:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private func imageCard(title: String, subtitle: String) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Color.white
                .frame(height: 150)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6))
            ThreeLineText(title: title, subtitle: subtitle)
        }
        .frame(width: 150)
        .padding()
        .background {
            Color(white: 0.85)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) {
            imageCard(
                title: "Title that wraps to two lines",
                subtitle: "Subtitle wrapped to two lines"
            )
            imageCard(
                title: "Title is short",
                subtitle: "Subtitle wrapped to two lines"
            )
            imageCard(
                title: "Title is short",
                subtitle: "Subtitle is short"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I realized there is an empty case for title and subTitle also. So I will retain placeHolder as dummy text. Btw, your SwiftUI layout answers are still fantastic, you rock, keep going.

Comment: @son Thanks for the positive feedback! Regarding empty cases, the OP shows that the outer container holding the white frame + text is always the same height. So assuming this height is determined by the contents instead of being fixed, it appears that it is actually a requirement that the text block always has the same height, even when there are less than three lines. On the other hand, if the container height is fixed then the (simpler) solution by *Stoic* should work.

Comment: Hmm, you were right. I was thinking about dynamic height from the 'inner three line' Text, which depends on Font.